# 404 Page Not Loading Images (File Source / Layers Problem)

Tags: image, directory, hyperlink, subdirectory, custom-error-pages

I'm facing what could be a simple problem, but haven't been able to find any solutions yet.

I just recently built a **simple 404 page on my website** (*nofound.html*) which through a *.htaccess* redirection (*ErrorDocument 404 /nofound.html*) allows me to catch all URL errors and such. Basic.

The problem is that, since the 404 response can be called *within different directories*, say for example *index*, or */dir1*, or */dir1/dir2*, etc, the page is **not loading its styles and images right**, since the source paths do not link correctly (*image.png* links correctly from *index/nofound.html*, but should become *../image.png* and so on when going into different directory layers).

I've managed to make the styles load correctly by loading the same stylesheet twice (*styles.css* AND *../styles.css*), but for the images, I have not found any workaround yet (other than duplicating the image within layered directories, which is cumbersome and redundant).

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it does not follow best practices, my final solution was to simply **use absolute hyperlinks** (such as *https://website/img.png* or something like that) rather than relative links within the website's anchors (*../../img.png*)

As such, every element on the page is loaded **from its absolute -actual- directory**, regardless of the relative relationship between the *nofound.html* result and the rest of the site architecture.